# does HttpUrlConnection.disconnect close the InputStream?

Tags: android

is the InputStream still usable after a disconnect() is called ?

I want to create a helper class for HTTP requests that will return the InputStream, but closes the connection. is it possible ?

for example:

```
public InputStream Get(String url) {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    HttpUrlConnection con = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = con.getInputStream();
    } finally {
        con.disconnect();
    }

    return in;
}
```

Comment: `in = com.getInputStream();` ???? what does com for ? It looks like you have spelling mistake in your code.

Comment: @Lucifer typo I guess: HttpUrlConnection con

Comment: @LazyNinja, look at the indentation its pure copy paste from eclipse, then how it can be typo mistake ?

Comment: it was a typing mistake, this is just an example for my question and not the actual method I'll use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible. an inputstream is just a pipe to the server, it doesn't contain any data.
you may do like this:

```
public byte[] Get(String url) {
URL u = new URL(url);
byte [] data = null
HttpUrlConnection con = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = con.getInputStream();
    data = readDataFromStream(in);
} finally {
    con.disconnect();
}

return data;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Before you disconnect con, make sure you have read the InputStream though!